Using whole training set for choosing model
I am working on a classification problem with what I understand as a big dataset. I have first of all splitted it in my "train" dataset and the "test" one. (Actually I am convinced I should do this before the EDA, but not sure). I have done all the preprocessing and now I have to choose a model. I am trying the following models:

Logistic regression with gridsearch for C parameter [10e-3, 10e-2, 10e-1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
Decision tree classifier with gridsearch for max depth  [None, 3, 5, 7, 9]
Support vector machine with ggridsearch for C parameter [10e-2, 1, 100] and kernel ['linear', 'rbf']
Random forest classifier with a large gridsearch:

'clas__n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
'clas__max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
'clas__min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
'clas__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
'clas__bootstrap': [True, False]


Gradient boosting classifier with also many parameters:

'clas__n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
'clas__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
'clas__max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
'clas__min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
'clas__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4]



And a few more simple models as GaussianNB and KNN.
I am evaluating them through a cross validation with cv=10 over my "train" dataset after preprocessing. The size of this dataset is around 70.000 observations of 90 features and I am computing the trainings locally in my computer. I am afraid it will take too long to finish all the trainings and I was wondering if it possible to use a small sample of the dataset to choose the model or other technic I am missing. Every help is well recieved, thank you.
I have to mention that I have more or less a week to complete this problem, so I am worried I need to wait some days for each training, even if I want to retrain random forest or gradient boosting with less features or something like this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
